# how to make http call inside asynchronous form validation method in angular 2 final?

Tags: forms, validation, http, angular, asynchronous

I am using Angular 2 final version and trying for asynchronous form validation. In my component I am having below code in constructor:

```
this.myForm = this._formBuilder.group({
        'firstName': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(45), ValidationService.nameValidator])],
        'userName': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required]), Validators.composeAsync([ValidationService.userNameValidator])],
        'userEmail': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, ValidationService.emailValidator])],
        'confirmEmail': ['', Validators.required],
        'password': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, ValidationService.passwordValidator])],
        'confirmPassword': ['', Validators.required]
        });
```

I am trying to check like if username entered already exists in db via http call.

Validation method is as below:

```
static userNameValidator(control: FormControl){
    let http: Http;
    if ( control.value.trim().length === 0 ) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve(null);
        });
    }
    if (control.value) {
        console.log('value:' + control.value);
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                var url = '/isUserNameUnique/';//this is getting printed
                console.log('url is ' + url);
                http.get(url + control.value + '/').map(response => response.json()).subscribe(result => {
                    if (result === false) {
                        resolve({'userAlreadyInUse': true});
                    } else {
                        resolve(null);
                    }
                });
            }, 1000);
        });
    }
}
```

The console is getting printed. But http call is not made. Error says

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
```

Can somebody help me to understand what is the issue exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't used `http` by taking it from depedency. I'd say define class with static method in it. Then ask for `http` dependency in constructor and use it wherever you want it.

**Code**

```
@Injectable()
export class MyClass {
  constructor(private http: Http) {}
  static userNameValidator(control: FormControl) {
    if (control.value.trim().length === 0) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve(null);
      });
    }
    if (control.value) {
      console.log('value:' + control.value);
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          var url = '/isUserNameUnique/'; //this is getting printed
          console.log('url is ' + url);
          //used http as this.http 
          this.http.get(url + control.value + '/').map(response => response.json())
          .subscribe(result => {
            if (result === false) {
              resolve({
                'userAlreadyInUse': true
              });
            } else {
              resolve(null);
            }
          });
        }, 1000);
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: i used like what you have given initially- like having http in constructor and then using it inside static method as this. It wont allow. So I put MyClass.http. Errors were not there. But same error like 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined'.

Comment: @revathi before using `MyClass` you have to make it `@Injectable`& import the static method wherever you want it. and then use it.

Comment: yes that I did already. My Class is annotated with '@Injectable' as it is a service and this service is being imported on the component. Also service and component is declared in declarations and providers array of app.module.ts as well. Still no hop.

Comment: @revathi can you please create a small plunkr so that I can play with it.

Comment: sorry for the delay in reply. the problem got solved. what i did was i made the method non static. then i put http dependency in constructor. then i changed like ---->>>  'userName': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required]), Validators.composeAsync([this._validationService.userNameValidator.bind(this._validationService)])]

Comment: That means problem was with.context

Comment: @revathi Really great solution. Can you explain what your code is doing which is in comment and what was the problem, how can I execute validation in series like first `Validators.required` then `Validators.email` then `Validators.composeAsync([this._validationService.userNameVal‌​idator.bind(this._va‌​lidationService)])`